# How to update one but return all documents in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Are there is any way to find document by id, update it and return all the documents?

My model is Painting and it contains objects of products. I can update and get one product, but can I get all products?

```js
  Painting.findAndModify(
    { _id: objectId },
    { $set: productBody },
    { new: false },
    (err, paintings) => {
    console.log(paintings)
    })
    .populate("style")
    .populate("subject")
```

**That is how I managed to get it, not sure if it is the best approach.**

```js
   Painting.updateOne(
        { _id: objectId},
        {$set: productBody},
        { multi: true },
      ).then(painting => {
        if(painting.nModified === 1){
          Painting.find((err,painting)=>{
            if (err) return res.json({ success: false, err });
            res.status(200).json({
              success: true,
              product: painting
        });
          })
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
To retrieve the documents while modifying, you can use collection.findOneAndUpdate() instead of findAndModify().

Set the returnNewDocument as true and you will get updated document.

collection.findOneAndUpdate(
 { verificationHash: req.query.hash }, // query
 { $unset: {verificationHash: ''}},  // update condition
 { returnNewDocument: true }, // returns updated document
  function (err, documents) {
        res.send({ error: err, affected: documents });
        db.close();
    }
 )
```

Comment: But that only returns the object that I am updating. I need to return all of the objects. 
I edited what I did on top to get it. But not sure if it is the best approach.

Comment: I don't think you can get all the documents in the update query.

Comment: great.. can you share the query?

Comment: I edited my question and added it, you can see it at the top.